# Does using ForEach with push to create an output array in javascript Anti-Pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Does using ForEach with push to create an output array in javascript Anti-Pattern? Or is it better to use Map?

```
const result = [];
arr.forEach(element => {
  result.push(element.name)
})
```

Comment: It's not *forbidden*, but it's pretty strange to use `forEach` when a more appropriate method exists

Comment: For a simple case like this, `map` is *cleaner*. However, if you need to perform any sort of filtering **and** mapping, often `forEach` is better than a separate `filter` and `map` combination as you reduce the amount of times you need to loop over an array. You can also use `reduce` for that if you're comfortable with it.